# why i am getting syntax error in ELIF command in the last steps.?

Tags: python

```
if choice =="0":
    print(good-bye)
elif choice =="1":
    term = input("What term do you want me to translate?: ")
    if term in geek:
        definition = geek[term]
        print("\n", term, "means", definition)
else:
    print("\nSorry, I dont know", term)
elif choice == "2":
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

> > > elif choice =="2":

SyntaxError: unexpected indent

> > > elif choice =="2":

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: since your original code is quite tough to format and read, it's hard to give you a clear answer, but for sure print(good-bye) will not work, replace with `print('good-bye')`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you have an elif after your last else. Elif can only be after an if statement, and else has to be the last choice.

Here is what the code would look like:

```
    if choice =="0":
       print(good-bye)
    elif choice =="1":
       term = input("What term do you want me to translate?: ")
       if term in geek:
          definition = geek[term]
          print("\n", term, "means", definition)
    elif choice == "2":
       do something
    else:
       print("\nSorry, I dont know", term)
```

Comment: It's more likely the `else` belongs to the inner `if`.

Comment: If that's the case then the error is because of the indentation, with else being indented as if it is under the first elif.